# Speed up a loop in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am struggling with an issue on Python Pandas, I have a DataFrame which represents connection on a website:

```
No.      IDs      date                    duration_since_last_visit
 1      4678     2012-11-30 23:59:59                0
 2      4703     2012-11-30 23:59:23                0
 3      4678     2012-11-30 23:58:46                73s
 4      5803     2012-11-30 23:58:19                0
 5      4678     2012-11-30 23:58:07                39s
```

I am trying to find a way to know the mean time of visit for each ID number. I managed to do that thanks to:

```
for i in df['IDs'].values:
    report['mean_time_visits']=report[report['IDs']==i].duration_since_last_visit.mean()
```

But my array has 350 000 rows and the result takes for ever to compute, I wanted to know if I did something wrong and if there's a way to do this task faster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No loops needed.

```
In [12]: df.groupby('IDs')['duration_since_last_visit'].mean()
Out[12]: 
IDs
4678    37.333333
4703     0.000000
5803     0.000000
Name: duration_since_last_visit, dtype: float64
```

You'll find that vectorized operations are more efficient in pandas / numpy.

Comment: Thank you! It is indeed much more faster

Comment: This is more than vectorization, though: this is a significant reduction in algorithmic complexity, dropping it to O(N).